# Playing Super Smash Bros (N64) with Master Hand?

Tags: super-smash-bros

I remember playing the N64 version of Super Smash Bros where you could play as master hand. Was it just my imagination or there's a way to do it?

Comment: It was possible in the *gamecube* version, with cheats. Are you perhaps thinking of that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Super Smash Bros. ***Melee*** is the only game you can play as Master Hand without using cheating devices like GameShark or Action Replay. The glitch for Melee was found a few years after the game came out and you can find a video of it [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMcP3kZvkDE) and a description of how to perform it [here](http://super-smash-bros.wikia.com/wiki/Master_Hand_glitch). However, as stated in [the wiki for master hand](http://super-smash-bros.wikia.com/wiki/Master_Hand#Playability)

> Though there are several "cheats" that supposedly allow Master Hand to
>   be played as a normal character, most of them are false [...]
>   However, one glitch works for controlling Master Hand in SSBM.

So you need a Gameshark to play Master Hand in the N64 or Wii games.

Apparently the GameShark codes to play him (for the N64 version) are:

```
Master Hand in Vs mode:
800A4D2B 000C<-----player 1
800A4D9F 000C<-----player 2
800A4E13 000C<-----player 3
800A4E87 000C<-----player 4

Master Hand in Story mode:
800A2AFB 000C<-----player 1
800A2B6F 000C<-----player 2
800A2BE3 000C<-----player 3
800A2C57 000C<-----player 4
```

Comment: This is confusing.  You link to the plugging/unplugging method, and link to a video as proof, and then say it doesn't actually work and you need codes?

Comment: It works in SSBM not in SSB. As stated in the quote from the wiki. I'll try to reword my answer to clarify.

Comment: Ah, so SSB requires the codes.  Thanks for clarifying!